# Changing list to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a list and from the list i want to extract the information and change into a data frame of two column-@TIME_PERIOD and @OBS_VALUE.

```
> dput(x<-SG.CPI$Obs)
list(structure(list(`@TIME_PERIOD` = c("2018-01", "2018-02", 
"2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", 
"2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", 
"2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", 
"2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", "2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", 
"2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05"), `@OBS_VALUE` = c("113.301770048184", 
"113.834901010394", "113.603801322912", "113.070670360702", "113.775410001735", 
"113.839477241829", "113.672444794441", "114.151805037287", "114.123203590816", 
"113.773121886018", "113.959603317005", "114.046551714275", "113.704478414488", 
"114.35201516258", "114.373752261898", "114.123203590816", "114.777604686061", 
"114.44926008058", "113.933289986252", "114.644893974438", "114.573962387191", 
"114.325701831827", "114.696376578085", "114.914891629119", "114.639173685144", 
"114.724978024555", "114.329134005404", "113.275456717431", "113.810875795359"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 29L)))
```

Comment: How about `x[[1]]` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(structure(list(`@TIME_PERIOD` = c("2018-01", "2018-02", 
"2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", 
"2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", 
"2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", 
"2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", "2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", 
"2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05"), `@OBS_VALUE` = c("113.301770048184", 
"113.834901010394", "113.603801322912", "113.070670360702", "113.775410001735", 
"113.839477241829", "113.672444794441", "114.151805037287", "114.123203590816", 
"113.773121886018", "113.959603317005", "114.046551714275", "113.704478414488", 
"114.35201516258", "114.373752261898", "114.123203590816", "114.777604686061", 
"114.44926008058", "113.933289986252", "114.644893974438", "114.573962387191", 
"114.325701831827", "114.696376578085", "114.914891629119", "114.639173685144", 
"114.724978024555", "114.329134005404", "113.275456717431", "113.810875795359"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 29L))))
```

```
df
```

Comment: The original column names are changed by `as.data.frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your list is saved as `ll`. Then you can assign `ll[[1]]`to an object, say, `df`:

```
df <- ll[[1]]
```

If you check the structure using `str`, you'll see you now have a dataframe:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   29 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ @TIME_PERIOD: chr  "2018-01" "2018-02" "2018-03" "2018-04" ...
 $ @OBS_VALUE  : chr  "113.301770048184" "113.834901010394" "113.603801322912" "113.070670360702" ...
```